# How to Handle PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and Drag and drop event Simultaneous in Wpf

Tags: wpf

I want to expose mouse doubleclick and PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown events in DataGrid in MVVM model. For this i have created two attached behaviour one doubleClick and another for 
Drag and Drop and Attached with DataGrid.My Problem is when i press mouse double click over any item of datagrid then PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown mouse button get invoked that's double click event does not fired.

Can any one tell me how to handle both mouse doubleclick and PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(Drag And Drop)Event Simultaneous in MVVM Model.

Thanks
Amit Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's hard to tell what your code is doing without you posting some of it, but here is an idea:

If your PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown interferes with double-click, that possibly means that you are marking event as handled. If you are doing that, then obviously stop, and instead capture your state with a few booleans and use them as conditions to do your logic.

On PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown set _IsMouseLeftButtonDown = true;

On PreviewMouseButtonUp set _IsMouseLeftButtonDown = false and _IsDragging = false;

In Drag-Drop check if(_IsMouseLeftButtonDown) IsDragging =true + to do your logic..